# Zend validation errors extraction for gettext

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, translate

I'm building an application using ZF 1.12. App will be available in two languages - polish and english. For translation i am using gettext adapter and it works pretty well. BUT! I have already translated whole interface and messages and only thing that I can't figure out how to translate are validation errors. Problem is that during form validation, all errors that are passed to translate() are variables not pure strings so I can't extract them from code. Of course I can create separate file with all errors as strings, or use xgettext with -a option to translate all strings in Zend_Validate package but I'm looking for smarter solution... Does anyone have such solution? I will be greatful, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this article could help you: http://phpmaster.com/setting-custom-error-messages-for-zend_form_element/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using arrays. If you say that all errors are passed to `translate()` function, then, you can use an array like this:

```
array(
    'type_of_error_1' => array(
        0 => array('language' => 'en', 'message' => 'In English for type_error_1'),
        1 => array('language' => 'po', 'message' => 'In Polish for type_error_1'),
    ),
    'type_of_error_2' => array(
        0 => array('language' => 'en', 'message' => 'In English for type_error_2'),
        1 => array('language' => 'po', 'message' => 'In Polish for type_error_2'),
    ),
    ...
);
```

and display the message for any kind of error and in correct language.